# What's the difference between Autowire and Resouce annotations in Spring? Why I cannot substitute Resouce with Autowire?

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control, autowired, java-ee-6

I am trying to use Redis in Spring project. And I copied some code like this and it works well:

```java
    @Autowired
    private RedisTemplate redisTemplate;

    @Resource(name = "redisTemplate")
    private HashOperations<String, String, SomeObject> hashOps;
```

Notice that I defined 2 variables pointing to a same bean `RedisTemplate`, which is constructed in another file:

```java
@Configuration
public class RedisConfig {

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate redisTemplate(
          RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
          @Qualifier("customObjectMapper")  ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
// do the config things...
    }
}
```

===

Then an idea came up to me, I am wondering why the var of `redisTemplate` wearing `@Autowire` while the var of `hashOps` wearing `@Resource`, and why `hashOps` can work well as there is not a bean injected explicitly.

I replaced `Autowire` to the var `hashOps` as below:

```java
    @Autowired
    private RedisTemplate redisTemplate;

    @Autowired(name = "redisTemplate") // instead of Resouce here
    private HashOperations<String, String, SomeObject> hashOps;
```

Expected enough, my App started failed. The spring container tells that there is no bean of HashOperations to look up.

Emm, so back to the caption: What's the difference between Autowire and Resouce annotations in Spring? Why I cannot substitute Resouce with Autowire?

Comment: I'm actually surprised it works as the `RedisTemplate` isn't even a `HashOperations`. Looking into it it appeas as if `@Resource` passes through the conversion framework of Spring as there is a `HashOperationsEditor` which converts a `RedisOperations` into the `HashOperations` by calling the factory method. This appears to be bypassed by `@Autowired` might be due to the point into the lifecycle that this is being invoked.

Comment: @M.Deinum Yes it works and I found why :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes guys, I figured it out by a Chinese post here: https://xxgblog.com/2020/03/12/spring-redistemplate-listoperations/.

Don't worry if you can't read Chinese. I looked up the newest official document of why we can use Resouce instead of Autowire: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-redis/docs/3.2.x/reference/html/#redis:template

The KEY is spring framework helps us to do the conversion things. Spring provides more than you imaged types linked to specific Redis operation type, such as `ListOperations` ,`HashOperations` ,`ValueOperations` ,`SetOperations` and many other so-called `operations view`s, which you can find in the doc above.